# PHP mail() sending Emails successfully, but not appearing in gmail

Tags: php, gmail

I am aware that this question been asked many times, but all the solutions I followed didn't work for my case.

I am trying to send basic `php mail()` function, I am receiving that `mail()` returning `TRUE` but the email not sent into my **gmail**. I did check spam folder and all!

**ADDITIONAL NOTE**
I don't have to use **gmail** to send emails from my **php** script, it can be any email!

I am using **Linux Mint**, my server is **XAMPP**

my **php.ini** :

```
[mail function]

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = 

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = 

; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header=On
```

**PHP Code** :

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_error_handler("var_dump");

$to = "my-email@gmail.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = 'From: same-email@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: same-email@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$res = mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);
if ($res){
    echo "Email Sent Succesfully<br>";
} else {
    echo "Error!<br>";
}
?>
```

**EDIT NOTE**
I found that I needed to install still `sendmail` and configure it a little but still after receiving success in terminal the email not appearing in gmail inbox:

```
echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -v my-email@gmail.com
```

RESULTS:

```
<omar@omarlx.home>... Connecting to local...
050 <omar@omarlx.home>... Sent
250 2.0.0 24OG5dE9090992 Message accepted for delivery
my-email@gmail.com... Sent (24OG5dE9090992 Message accepted for delivery)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
```

Comment: `mail()` returning true doesn't mean the mail was _sent_, it means it was _queued to be sent later_. There are still lots of reasons why it might not actually get sent. Start by checking your mail server logs.

Comment: You say _email not sent to Gmail_ Does that mean it is being sent to other email end  points or you have only tested Gmail?

Comment: May you mention where is mail server logs in XAMPP linux ? @AlexHowansky

Comment: Typically, `/var/log/mail` or similar. I'm not familiar with XAMPP specifically.

Comment: Didn't test other services, I meant is not being sent for this test case but I used gmail in description as its what I've used @RiggsFolly

Comment: You cannot send email that requires a user and password to work using the default `mail()` and the `php.ini` settings as there is no way to provide the password. I suggest you look at the phpMailer library if you want to send email via gmail as that will insist on a login

Comment: I am required to use ``mail()`` only, I may send with any other email but the receiver should be announced @RiggsFolly

Comment: Do you have a mail server configured on this server/pc

Comment: I only installed **XAMPP** on **Linux Mint** but didn't specifically install something for mail server

Comment: Remember, `mail()` does not send email, it just passes it on to an email server for that email server to do all the real work of transmitting email

Comment: gmail will not let you use their SMTP services unless you login. And you have no way of doing that using just `mail()` so you either have to have an email server installed and configure PHP to use it or you could use `sendmail`

Comment: [Have a look at this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost-using-php/)

Comment: I will have a look at this now and comment back with edits or solution if it worked! thanks @RiggsFolly

Comment: Use Swift or PHPMailer. PHP's mail function has poor error reporting

Comment: maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73544045/mail-php-sendmail-sending-to-gmail-not-working

Answer (score -1):

You should probably configure your Gmail to accept emails from thirds parts.
Have a look of this [Check Gmail through other email platforms](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en#zippy=%2Cstep-change-smtp-other-settings-in-your-email-client%2Cstep-check-that-imap-is-turned-on).
By default Imap and SMTP are off.

Comment: But that wont be an ideal solution, as I am going to send validation links to several user emails on whichever email service they are using, and I can't tell each user to configure their email to receive my message.

Comment: IMAP and SMTP are opposites, and likely unrelated here. IMAP and POP3 are more closely related, but neither should be affecting this user.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).